# Hard override entry in tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, tnsnames

I have a set of shell scripts and sqlplus commands.

These connect to Oracle DB_ONE and DB_TWO.

I am upgrading DB_ONE.

For my testing I override the DB_ONE entry in a local tnsnames.ora.
There exists a global tnsnames.ora with all connections in it.

`export TNS_ADMIN=/path/to/local/tnsnames:/path/to/global/tnsnames`

This way, I am able to connect to DB_ONE on my_new.server and DB_TWO on some.other.server as expected.

However, if I break my_new.server, sqlplus automatically connects to DB_ONE on original.server. So it fails silently and fails over to the connection in the global tnsnames file.  I would like this connection to fail completely.

Is there a way to have a 'hard' override such that sqlplus will only try a DB_ONE connection from the local tnsnames.ora, whilst being free to try DB_TWO connections from all tnsnames.ora files?

My local tnsnames.ora

```
DB_ONE=
        (DESCRIPTION=
                (ADDRESS_LIST=
                        (ADDRESS=
                        (PROTOCOL=TCP)
                        (PORT=1524)
                        (HOST=my_new.server)
                )
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA=
                (SERVICE_NAME=DB_ONE)
        )
        )
```

Global tnsnames.ora which I cannot change

```
DB_ONE=
        (DESCRIPTION=
                (ADDRESS_LIST=
                        (ADDRESS=
                        (PROTOCOL=TCP)
                        (PORT=1524)
                        (HOST=original.server)
                )
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA=
                (SERVICE_NAME=DB_ONE)
        )
        )

DB_TWO=
        (DESCRIPTION=
                (ADDRESS_LIST=
                        (ADDRESS=
                        (PROTOCOL=TCP)
                        (PORT=1524)
                        (HOST=some.other.server)
                )
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA=
                (SERVICE_NAME=DB_TWO)
        )
        )
```

Comment: How are you 'breaking' my_new.server? Which platform lets you colon-separate two paths for TNS_ADMIN - I've never seen that before? And how are you connecting from your scripts - you're trying to avoid changing `@DB_ONE` references? I'm not sure why you can't create your local tnsnames.ora as a complete copy of the global one and just modify the entry you want, then set TNS_ADMIN to just point to the local edited version.

Comment: For breaking my_new.server, let's say I stop the database.
TNS_ADMIN behaves like any other unix classpath variable, so sqlplus looks at the first available tnsname file, and then the second if the first is not useful. This is working for me on linux running bash. All connections are done by service name and yes, I want to be able to upgrade without changing DB_ONE references. Yes, I could copy the global file, but then I have to maintain it. A local file containing a 'patch' for one server is more maintainable for me.

Comment: I don't believe it does, it's a single path. If you have it set to an invalid value (as you would do with two real paths separated by a colon) it would default to `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`. I suspect you're always actually picking up that default (global?) file entry and never hit the instance on `my_new.server` - how are you verifying which instance you're actually connecting to?

Comment: Yes you're right! Just tried with the invalid TNS_ADMIN with both tnsnames files pointing at the broken database, and it still connects. So it's looking at the default as  you point out. Thank you - looks as if copying the global file is the thing to do.

Comment: On Unix you can also use local users file `~/.tnsnames.ora`. Note the leading dot in the filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid:

```
export TNS_ADMIN=/path/to/local/tnsnames:/path/to/global/tnsnames
```

TNS_ADMIN [is a single directory path](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/tnsnames.htm#NETRF259), not a searchable list like `$PATH` or `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` etc. The documentation mentions that:

> If the TNS_ADMIN environment variable is not set, then Oracle Net will check the ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory.

It doesn't say so, but it also defaults to checking the network/admin directory if the TNS_ADMIN variable does not point to a valid directory, and as your colon-seperated list isn't a valid directory path, it will use the `tnsnames.ora` under `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`.

That means your local 'override' file is never being used, and you were accessing which ever instance DB_ONE points to in the global file. It's not that the TNS entry from the second file is used if the first fails - that mechanism just doesn't exist. (You can have failover *within* a file but that's different).

Assuming you have connection strings using a TNS alias like `user/pwd@DB_ONE` and you can't change those for your testing, your only real option is to make a complete copy of the global file and just edit the entry for DB_ONE:

```
cp /path/to/global/tnsnames/tnsnames.ora /path/to/local/tnsnames/
edit /path/to/local/tnsnames/tnsnames.ora
export TNS_ADMIN=/path/to/local/tnsnames
```

Or as @ibre5041 mentioned in a comment, as you're on Linux you could skip the TNS_ADMIN environment variable and use `~/.tnsnames.ora` for your local copy.

As you mention that won't reflect any changes made to the global file, but presumably once you've finished your testing you can trash your local file or revert to the global TNS_ADMIN anyway.